# Why does the QMessageBox opened from QFileDialog::accept() does not stay on top on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I try to have with Qt a file dialog, which asks the user for confirmation if the chosen file does not exist. So basically the same you get with the Windows API via IFileDialog::SetOptions(FOS_CREATEPROMPT).

So I derived a new class from QFileDialog to overwrite QFileDialog::accept().
The new QFileDialogEx::accept() opens a QMessageBox when the user clicks on Open, but the file does not exist. If the user chooses "No", the file dialog will not be accepted and keeps open.

That works fine on Linux, but on macOS, the QMessageBox does not stay on top of the QFileDialog. So if the user clicks on the QFileDialog under the QMessageBox, it will come to the top, hiding the QMessageBox.

Here is my code:

```cpp
class QFileDialogEx : public QFileDialog
{
public:
    QFileDialogEx(QWidget *parent, const QString &caption, const QString &directory)
    : QFileDialog(parent, caption, directory) {
        this->setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);  
    }

    void accept(void) {
        QString    selectedFilePath = this->selectedFiles().value(0);
        QFileInfo  selectedFileInfo(selectedFilePath);
        if (!selectedFileInfo.exists()) {
            // File does not exist => Ask if file should be created
            QMessageBox msgBox(this);
            msgBox.setWindowFlags(msgBox.windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
            msgBox.setText(selectedFileInfo.fileName() + "\nThis file doesn't exist.\n\nDo you want to create this file?");
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Create Prompt");
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
            msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
            msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Yes);
            if (msgBox.exec() == QMessageBox::No)
                return; // Keep file dialog open
        }
        QFileDialog::accept();      
    }
};
```

I've searched a lot about keeping a QMessageBox box on top. Normally the point is: "Set the parent". But as you can see, I did that already. I also desperately tried Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint and msgBox.setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal) without success.

Just to be clear: I am *not* using the native file dialogs here. (QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialogs)

Any idea how to let the QMessageBox stay on top of the QFileDialog also on macOS?

Or any other idea, on how to implement a prompt when the user clicks on Open, but the chosen file does not exist?